# Power Bi Tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

In Power Bi In the image below i need to have a display to say yes Team 3 can go to their next job depending on the results. In the first and second table they need to have above 95 for it to be green. The 2 bottom tables are solved jobs and callouts they need to be sorted with in 0 - 5 days to be in green. In the extra display (not sure which one to go with yet) if Team 3 are green in all 4 Tables then they can move to their next job anything less the 95% or took more that 5 days to solve the then no they cant move to the next job
[image]

Comment: Update your question with easier to read/understand formatting, include [markdown table(s)](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) to help us visualize, and make it clear on your ask or desired result.

Comment: Update your question with what the logic should be. Tbl1 Green, Tbl2 Green, Tbl3 Yellow, Tbl4 ? What is Table 4? Share a screen grab of your data model.